# Xcode 6.4 Storyboard Crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, storyboard

I have recently been having a problem with Xcode (6.3, 6.4 & 7.0) when opening a storyboard file, Xcode will crash with this [error log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtlszfoe0uckajb/XcodeCrash.txt?dl=0).

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: This happens with existing projects and new ones.

Comment: Did you happen to update to the latest El Capitan beta?

Comment: I did update to the latest El Capitan Build today, is this a known problem?

Comment: Welcome to the club http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803585/anyone-elses-xcode-6-4-crashing-after-el-capitan-beta-6

Comment: Great, exactly what I need just before an App Store submission!  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Don't use beta's on production devices. Thats why it's a beta

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this on [cyril's SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803585/anyone-elses-xcode-6-4-7-crashing-after-el-capitan-beta-6/31833021#31833021) now.

Take a look at it, the solution should work for iOS and watchOS development.

Answer (score 1):

I read that it could be an autolayout issue, so I disable it manually and bingo! its work for me!

Just click on storyboard and select File inspector and uncheck "Use auto Layout" option.[image]