# Xcode 6.4/7 crashing after El Capitan beta

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan

I updated my computer to the latest beta that was released to developers last night and the same project that was compiling fine yesterday night now fails due to a supposed .xib/.storyboard error.

I have tried cleaning the project, downloading a previous version off of github, etc.. and yet the project still gives me the following error. `"Failed to communicate with Interface Builder"` as well as `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255`. Literally nothing was changed with the .storyboard  file or anything remotely related to it.

What's more is that trying to open any .xib/.storyboard file (even the launch screen xib which I haven't touched leads to Xcode crashing which leads me to think this has nothing to do with me.)

Anyone else experiencing this? Any advice or temporary fixes?

**Update**: Trying to run anything on the simulator causes it to crash continuously or hang with the following error message: `"Springboard quit unexpectedly"`

**Update 2**: Playgrounds are unusable but do not crash.
Also, these lads seem to be in the same boat as we are. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13170

This is why we can't have nice things, Apple.

Comment: It happens to me too. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Same here. Been looking all night, there are no workarounds. None of the Xcode Betas work either. It's a problem with ElCap beta 6.

Comment: Developers all around the world are suffering from this issue... Apple has some serious quality issue with their regression tests here.

Comment: The solution that seems to work for people is installing beta 5 on top of 6...

Comment: @cyril That's not a solution. So far, people lose sound, and who knows what other bugs will be revealed.

Comment: Latest xCode 7 beta works for me, but that is useless for compiling for submission.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A workaround was found thanks to "lembacon" on the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13170?start=105&tstart=0).

In Terminal:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app (or wherever your Xcode 7 beta 4 is located)  
cd Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform  
cd Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib  
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

Seems to work for iOS projects but watchOS is iffy.

**EDIT:**
watchOS solution:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app (or wherever your Xcode 7 beta 4 is located)  
cd Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform  
cd Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/lib  
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

**Another Edit:** As mentioned by sciasxp, this also works for 6.4.  Hopefully we'll get new iOS and Xcode betas soon that permanently fix this.

**Another Another Edit:** A new iOS beta is out today, as well as a new Xcode beta.  This issue should be resolved.

Comment: The build now succeeds and storyboards open (after a scary beachball-filled delay)

Comment: Works for me too! Thanks!

Comment: I have a script to do this [gisted](https://gist.github.com/claybridges/f644b952ee66cc311614).

Comment: strangely i had to move both the sim and watchOS files until xcode started working again. using only the iPhoneSim file caused my xcode to crash even when opening source files. Thanks for this fix!!

Comment: These commands are now an 'official' Apple suggestion, posted by Apple Staff in the [dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/37126). Additionally, the post recommends reversing the command when Apple releases the next 10.11 beta.

Answer (score 5):

There is one weird fix :

Reinstall Beta 5 by downloading and running the following directly from Apple's CDN. This will restore Xcode but you will loose sound :)

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/43/22/031-29032/71ihp9c54k547fvol25w5g85z9323gqwnr/OSXUpd10.11.pkg

http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/43/22/031-29032/71ihp9c54k547fvol25w5g85z9323gqwnr/FirmwareUpdate.pkg

Comment: Do I need to install both of those packages? Also, is there a fix for the sound or are we screwed until the next beta?

Comment: no, afaik, it does not require that firmware update, and... yeah we are all screwed until the next update. :(

Comment: After reinstall to beta 5 sound does not work. Just follow Zev Eisenbergs solution this is correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 7.0 beta 5 is out with support for El Capitan beta 6.

[Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_5/Xcode_7_beta_5_Release_Notes.pdf)

> Xcode 7 beta 5 resolves issues with building iOS projects and running
>   the iOS simulator on OS X El Capitan beta 6. (22089926)

Answer (score 0):

Running xcode 7.0.1 on ElCapitan with all updates installed and xcode is quitting often as above but not quire often enough that I cant develop for it.  Seems to occur when setting constraints and positions in storyboard.  iMac is latest and restarted at least once a week as off on weekends so stable as I can make it.

As with every release of Apple we just need to wait for the updates for xcode and or ElCapitan to fix it.

So rule is to save/build often to save code before playing around with constraints as its liable to just quit on you.

Comment: Actually it seems to be when editing anything with storyboard where it just crashed and quits unexpectedly.  Was editing uiscrollview and that caused it to quit unexpectedly.   If it happens again I will try and dig deeper.

Answer (score -5):

It's documented in the El Capitan Beta 6 [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/OS_X/OS_X_El_Capitan_10.11_beta_6_Release_Notes/OS_X_El_Capitan_Developer_Beta_6_Release_Notes.rtf), so you cannot blame Apple if you didn't read them.

> **Known Issues**
>
> - Xcode 6.x has known compatibility issues when run on OS X El Capitan. It is strongly encouraged that you use Xcode 7 when running
>     on OS X El Capitan.

**EDIT** Mostly the tone of this answer was brought about by the "This is why we can't have nice things, Apple." statement in question, implying the OP thinks he has a god-given right to use beta operating systems without impunity.

Comment: Unfortunately they failed to mention those problems also affect Xcode 7 ;)

Comment: The problem is Xcode 7 b4 is not working, too. :( Maybe, this question's title should be changed.

Comment: The most generic and unuseful answer. Just like stating "It's a beta, what did you expect". That statement has been there since first developer beta, but for the most part it was indeed working up until beta 6, where Apple decided to release a developer beta of their operating system, where no development can be done. This is not a proper answer and should be deleted.

Comment: @LeoNatan Apple have stated it doesn't work.  That means if you want to use Xcode 6 then you should not install El Capitan.  In order to use Xcode 6 in first few El Capitan betas, then you had to use a workaround, so it's not true to say that it has been working.

Comment: It is very true. First two betas required workaround, then it worked. Now Xcode 7 doesn't work either.

Comment: @LeoNatan Yeah El Capitan beta 6 is totally broken.  It didn't even complete installation on my ageing MBP and I had to boot the recovery partition in order re-install El Capitan beta 1 via Wifi. I then had install all the betas up to 5.

Comment: For me it installed, but if I can't develop on it, why do I even bother? `:-)` Terrible QA by Apple, something that occurs regularly these days. Remember the rigorous "QA Nazi" days of Steve Jobs? Nope, not any more.

Comment: @trojanfoe that was merely a joke. I can't take responsibility for you feeling attacked by my making a joke about a third party...