# My Xcode 7 beta 4 can`t work since I update OS 10.11 beta 6... Is there any method to resolve it?

Tags: beta, osx-elcapitan, xcode7-beta4

There are many guys that meet the same question.It still doesn`t work now.

Comment: Some detail perhaps?

Comment: Once I click the storyBoard,Xcode will have no response.

Comment: Besides, when I run my App on iOS simulator 9,Xcode will crash and push an error window(something has wrong with springBoard)...

Comment: many error too. When i try to launch the Simulator, SpringBoard quit... Uninstall all Xcode but same problem. On two different machine. Restore to the 10.11 beta 4 is the solution for me...

Comment: i found this in apple forum, we are not alone :)
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13170

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803585/anyone-elses-xcode-6-4-7-crashing-after-el-capitan-beta-6/31833021#31833021).

That fixes the problem with iOS and watchOS testing.